# What is the best datatype for a binary file like image in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, binaryfiles

I wanted to know the best practice in selecting the best datatype for my binary file (probably an image) with the current grails project I am working in. I have considered `byte[]`. You suggestions is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are right, and `byte[]` is the way to go

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @tim_yates, byte[] is your choice, and if you're persisting it to a database, you should add a mapping:

```
class SomePersistent {
   byte[] image

   static mappings = {
      image type: "blob"
   }
}
```

(Not compiled, might be slightly different syntax, check the Grails manual)

Answer (score 0):

I am using byte[], but make sure in the database hibernate/GORM is creating the right datatype. I am using mySQL and it creates tinyblob, and my images are too large for that.
I had to go back in the database and alter it to large blob to get it working.